# Is there a way to asyncrounously upload files to Firebase Storage and store links on Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am building a Flutter Firebase app that has a photo upload functionality. The file is uploaded to Firebase storage and the URL is stored to a Firestore collection. This is easy to achieve, however, I have a challenge when it comes to awaiting the upload to complete when the user is offline.

I create the storage reference:

```
       final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
             FirebaseStorage.instance
                         .ref()
                           .child(
                               'uploaded ${DateTime.now()}');
```

Then upload task:

```
      final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(
                                                    additionalImage);
```

Then download URL

```
    var downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask
                     .onComplete)
                      .ref
                      .getDownloadURL();
```

What is the best way of making this work offline especially when I have multiple files.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to use a [Cloud Storage trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) so when a file is uploaded successfully, the Firestore collection is written from this trigger (using `firebase-admin`), not from your client.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: how is uploading going to work when the user is offline?

Comment: Great idea. let me try this. Thanks